# Tag "third-party-libraries" and "3rd-party-library"

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

Aren't these tags more or less the same: [third-party-libraries](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/third-party-libraries) and [3rd-party-library](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3rd-party-library)? Should they be a synonym, or are they different?

Comment: by the way I got [funny error message](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlUE7.png "screen shot") when tried to suggest a [synonym](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tags/third-party-libraries/synonyms): I've been told that "3rd-party..." would make a "version specific" synonym. Guess UI just blindly looks for digits in the name and assumes that their presence indicates version

Comment: @gnat You should post that as a bug report.

Comment: @YannisRizos bug reported... more than a year ago: [Version Specific Tag Validation on Tag Synonym Page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121457/165773) - OP got that message trying to synonymize "nine-patch" and "9patch" at SO :)

Comment: @gnat As I haven't nor will unlikely ever moderate, I am not familiar with your tools, but can you create the synonym in the other direction? Starting with 'third-party...'  Also, I am guessing you looked at the linked topic within that pointed to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157869/version-specific-synonyms-can-only-be-created-by-moderators

Comment: @JustinC as far as I can tell, currently "third-..." is a _master_ tag, meaning it is considered over "3rd-..." (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tags/third-party-libraries/synonyms) - are you OK with this?

Comment: @gnat Short of having a moderator create the synonym as the linked article suggested, I am ok with that.  Better that a relationship exists even if the characterization is non standard, than none at all.  Can the change not be reverted [without significant consequence]?

Answer (score 5):

If I would have to choose between them, I would not be able to tell the difference.

So, yes, I think they should be synonyms. As [third-party-libraries](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/third-party-libraries) has the most questions (28), I think that is the best option for the master tag.